# Flash (swf) can't play automatically in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

My web site has got swf files where their heights are smaller than `298px` and which are not auto-played in Google Chrome.

I tried `autoplay=true`, `play=true`, ... but with no success.

How can I play automatically those SWFs?

Example :

[image]

Comment: This will never happen, browsers have recently changed policies to prevent auto playback. You can thank advertisers for this.

Comment: Are you sure about that? 
Because the same flashs play automaticly other web site.

Comment: Yes I'm sure: http://arstechnica.co.uk/information-technology/2015/08/google-chrome-will-block-auto-playing-flash-ads-from-september-1/

Comment: I already know that. But in http://www.kibrispostasi.com/ the flashs can play automaticly.. How this happen?

Comment: @HakanK. As a user you can permit to SWFs to be auto-played, but as a developer you can unfortunately do nothing if the browser block your SWF except demanding to your user to authorize your content to be played ...

Comment: Your browser probably remembered your preference, or maybe it is not yet affected by the paradigm shift yet. Here's what [I see](http://imgur.com/hxmF19h);

Comment: @Replete, what browser & OS? Either you got Flash disabled or you need a more capable browser. I'm on Chrome on Windows and yet I can see the Flash banner.

Comment: @HakanK. is the SWF file you are loading on same server as your page? If it's being loaded from a known advert server then it wont work... For example that site **http://kibrispostasi.com** works because all SWFs come from `http://kibrispostasi.com...` etc

Comment: @VC.One  Thank you bro! Really thank you! God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in more and more browsers.

It's time to embrace HTML5 and re-write or convert your `SWF`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd "><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd "><HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>
```

works for me, i think the issue is you have to work with html previous to html 5

Comment: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.